# How can I create a dockefile that uses nginx using proxy_pass in order to serve a fullstack application in one container? I aim to use cloud run

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-run, proxypass

My dockerfile looks somewhat like this: -- simplified

```
FROM ubuntu:22.10

# Create my_user ...

# Copy Nginx configuration files
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install \
    && npm run build

WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN npm install \
    && npm run build

RUN sudo cp -a ./dist/. /var/www/html

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["sh", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;' & npm run start:prod"]
```

This is my proxy.conf

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
user my_user;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # Other event configurations if needed
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    sendfile on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Locally this works like a charm but once deployed in cloud run and trying to access a path under /api like my_domain.bla/api/here/we/are I get a log from nginx saying:

`[error] 10#10: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: #certain_IP, server: _, request: "GET /api/here/we/are HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/here/we/are", host: "my_domain.bla""`

Nginx is listening on port 8080 and my backend app is running on port 3000 (I see clear logs coming from the container confirming the app is running fine and listening on the correct port)

I expect the proxy_pass to work on cloud run as well as it does locally. Does anybody understand the difference between cloud run and locally?
My first thought is that nginx might be trying to route the request to the host and not to the container internally. The backend port is not exposed so it would explain the connection refused but how do I fix that?

Comment: You should usually only run one process per container.  In your setup, if Nginx ever exits for any reason, the Docker ecosystem won't notice; and if the main application exits, it will take Nginx with it.  Can you run these in two separate containers?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Totally valid points. I have a healthcheck on the dockerfile to verify the container is running as expected. And I probably could run 2 services on cloud run splitting my app in frontend/nginx and backend and make sure one service can talk to the other.
However this setup is more complicated. That's why I wanted to have a quick way of testing my app within one container.
Do you have any idea why is this working locally and not on cloud run and how to solve it?

Comment: If your only reason to put both in one container is "this setup is more complicated", then you should split those 2 services up. It is not complicated, we can guide you through if you need, and it's definetly better practice and much easier to split those 2 services.

Comment: You are definitely right about being a better practice. Thanks for your input! I am interested in knowing why is this not woking on cloud run but it does work locally. How come splitting the services is easier if we didn't figure out the problem yet?

Comment: I recommend that you study the lifecycle of a Cloud Run application. Your app receives CPU cycles while servicing an HTTP request. Running processes in the background often means CPU starvation and network connection failure. Design apps for Cloud Run instead of trying to fit your app into Cloud Run for the best results.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and very nice hint. I am just very curious to understand the problem, not specifically attached to this setup. It seems like the CPU picked at 11% but is usually around 2%. I am the only one doing requests and they are very few... I might be wrong but it seems like CPU starvation is not the reason why the setup is not working.

Comment: You are seeing average CPU utilization. When an HTTP request is received, your container is allocated CPU cycles. When the HTTP response is returned, no CPU cycles. Your container uses network connections between Nginx and your app. No CPU cycles result in network failure, things timeout, etc etc etc.

Comment: Tip: enable CPU always allocated for your app and retest. However, there are costs to have an instance always running. Details [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation).

Comment: Nice!! That was indeed the problem! Thanks a lot!! I will definitely change my setup but it's very nice to finally understand what's going on.

Comment: If you write the explanation as an answer I will be happy to accept it @JohnHanley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Nginx application requires more CPU time than your current Cloud Run configuration provides. This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run) on the lifecycle of a container will show how CPU time is allocated.

Enable `CPU always allocated` for your Cloud Run instance.

There are additional costs when the CPU is always allocated. Review this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation) for more details.